# Proving by induction that $(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_{n+j})^i=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction

I am working with the polynomial ring $R=\dfrac{\mathbb Z_2[x_1,\cdots,x_{2n}]}I$ where $$I=\left\langle x_i\,x_{n+i}\,,\,x_1+x_{n+1}\,,\,x_i+\sum_{j=1}^{i}x_{n+j}\text{ for } 2\leq i\leq n\right\rangle$$

For convenience we shall denote the class of $x_i$ as $x_i$ itself.

> **Question :** Prove that $x_{n+i}^{i+1}=0$ in $R$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

**Attempt :** (by induction on $i$)

Clearly for $i=1$ we get $x_{n+1}^2=0$ as follows - $$x_{n+1}(x_1+x_{n+1})=0\implies \underbrace{x_1\,x_{n+1}}_{=\,0}+x_{n+1}^2=0\implies x_{n+1}^2=0$$

Let us assume that $x_{n+j}^{j+1}=0$ for all $1\leq j\leq i-1$ and we have to prove that $x_{n+1}^{i+1}=0$.

Now $x_{n+i}^i\left(x_i+\sum_{j=1}^{i}x_{n+j}\right)=0\implies x_{n+i}^{i+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_{n+j}x_{n+i}^i$

We can keep substituting for powers of $x_{n+i}$ and end up with $$x_{n+i}^{i+1}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_{n+j}\right)^ix_{n+i}$$

We will be done if we can show that $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_{n+j}\right)^i=0$$ I tried it for small values of $i$ and it happens to be 0 however I am struggling to prove it in general. So I tried it by induction on $i$ again but I am having trouble at the induction step -

Assuming $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-2}x_{n+j}\right)^{i-1}=0$ and writing $\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_{n+j}\right)^i=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-2}x_{n+j}+x_{n+i-1}\right)^i$ and then use binomial expansion. But I am getting no where. It is getting too complicated.

Thank you.

Comment: You are right. Now let me restate your question as follows: $$a_1^2=0, a_2(a_1+a_2)=0,\dots,a_n(a_1+\cdots+a_n)=0\implies (a_1+\cdots+a_t)^{t+1}=0$$ for $t=1,\dots,n$. We show by induction that all the monomials in $a_1,\dots,a_t$ of degree $t+1$ are zero. Let me show by an example how the things work: suppose you know this for $t=1,2$ and want to show it for $t=3$. A monomial $a_1^ia_2^ja_3^k$ with $i+j+k=4$ is zero if $k=0,1$ (by the previous case). If $k=2$ then $i+j=2$ and show that $a_1^ia_2^ja_3^2=0$ by multiplying $a_3^2=-(a_1+a_2)a_3$ with $a_1^ia_2^j$.

Comment: (Note that $a_1^{i+1}a_2^j=0$ since $i+1+j=3$, and similarly $a_1^ia_2^{j+1}=0$.) If $k=3$ then $i+j=1$ and one can show that $a_1^ia_2^ja_3^2=$ by multiplying $a_3^3=-(a_1+a_2)a_3^2$ with $a_1^ia_2^j$, and using the previous case. Finally, for $k=4$ we get $a_3^4=0$ from $a_3^4=-(a_1+a_2)a_3^3$, and the previous case. (As you can see, I didn't want to give values to $i$ and $j$ in order to give insight how to proceed in the general case. Actually I did the general case, and it works, but is hard to write it. You can post an answer if you figure out what I wanted to say.)

Comment: @user26857, Thank you. I think I get it. I will try the general case.

Comment: I was making some computations with the cohomology ring in $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients of some toric varieties. This is one of them. Some further computations are simplified if I assume $x_{n+i}^{i+1}=0$ so I was hoping to prove this :)

Comment: Great. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by user26857, I have got the answer to this question-

Let us restate the problem as follows - $$a_1^2=0\ ,\ a_2(a_1+a_2)=0\ ,\cdots,\ a_n(a_1+\cdots+a_n)=0\ \implies\ (a_1+\cdots+a_t)^{t+1}=0\quad\text{for } 1\leq t\leq n$$
Here addition and multiplication is mod 2.

> We will show by induction that every monomial in $a_1,\cdots,a_t$ of degree $t+1$ is zero.

When $t=1$ we have $a_1^2=0$.

Suppose every monomial in $a_1,\cdots,a_t$ of degree $t+1$ is zero for $t<k$ , we have to show that every monomial in $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ of degree $k+1$ is zero.

Let $a_1^{i_1}\,a_2^{i_2}\cdots a_k^{i_k}$ be a monomial such that $i_1+\cdots+i_k=k+1$.

**Case 1** - When $i_k=0$ we have a monomial in $a_1,\cdots,a_{k-1}$ of degree $k+1$ which is zero since we already have by the induction hypothesis that such a monomial of degree $k$ is zero.

**Case 2** - $i_k=1$ then removing the term $a_k$ we obtain a monomial in $a_1,\cdots,a_{k-1}$ of degree $k$ which is zero by the induction hypothesis.

**Case 3** - $2\le i_k\le k+1$. We have $i_1+\cdots+i_{k-1}=k+1-i_k$. Now $$a_k(a_1+\cdots+a_k)=0\implies a_k^{i_k-1}(a_i+\cdots+a_k)=0\implies a_k^{i_k}=(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-1})^{i_k-1}a_k$$
Thus we have 
\begin{equation}
a_1^{i_1}\,a_2^{i_2}\cdots a_k^{i_k}=a_1^{i_1}\,a_2^{i_2}\cdots a_{k-1}^{i_{k-1}}(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-1})^{i_k-1}a_k \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Consider the term $(a_1+\cdots+a_{k-1})^{i_k-1}$. This is a sum of monomials $a_1^{j_1}\,a_2^{j_2}\cdots a_{k-1}^{j_{k-1}}$ where $j_1+\cdots+j_{k-1}=i_k-1$. So (1) is a sum of monomials of the form $$a_1^{i_1+j_1}\,a_2^{i_2+j_2}\cdots a_{k-1}^{i_{k-1}+j_{k-1}}a_k$$

Now $a_1^{i_1+j_1}\,a_2^{i_2+j_2}\cdots a_{k-1}^{i_{k-1}+j_{k-1}}$ is a monomial in $a_i,\cdots,a_{k-1}$ of degree $i_1+\cdots+i_{k-1}+j_1+\cdots j_{k-1}=k+1-i_k+i_k-1=k$ and is zero by the induction hypothesis.

Hence the result. $\square$